# 3-way switch to control 2 fans independently

Tags: switch, ventilation, fans

I have a room where I need 2 ventilation fans.  One will be a regular bathroom fan, the other a much smaller fan powered through a timer in an outlet.  Both will be vented through the same duct to the outside and I don't want them both running at the same time.  Thinking of using a 3-way switch: up to turn on the bathroom fan, down to power an outlet. The outlet will be powered most of the time and only disconnected while the bathroom fan is on.

Not a typical scenario so wondering if there are any problems (code or otherwise) I could run into with that configuration.

Thx

Comment: Dunno about code, but electrically this is fine **except** you now have no way to turn both of them off!  Consider getting a  TPDT switch so you can have an "all off" position.

Comment: *a much smaller fan powered through a timer in an outlet* Do you mean "auto shutoff timer - e.g., turn it on and it runs for 15 minutes and then turns itself off" or do you mean "set it to run every day 9:00am - 9:30am, 2:00pm - 2:30pm or whatever times I want"? Those are two very different types of timers (in particular, the first can be mechanical rather than electronic).

Comment: The timer is electronic but according to specs will hold it's setting when power off.  "All off" position is worth considering though.

Comment: So you are using a cord-and-plug connection to supply the small fan, so you'll be able to use this model of timer that you like.  Is that fan normally plugged in: that is, does its labeling and instructions or NEC allow a cord-and-plug connection?

Comment: How are you going to keep the fans from backflowing through the duct for the other fan?

Comment: The smaller fan comes with an AC plug attached, so it's intended to be plugged in.  Regading backflow, one of the fans has integral backflow already.  For the other, I was planning to use something like this: https://www.amazon.ca/Backdraft-Damper-Duct-Backflow-Preventer/dp/B0822VQMHM/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=Backdraft-Damper-Duct-Backflow-Preventer&qid=1605373296&sr=8-3

Answer (score 1):

They make double switches that fit in the same box a single switch would. They come in two and three way combinations. This way you could use the three way as a selector and the other if you want both off. You could also control each individually.Also while you are at it consider when one fan is on will it exhaust back through the other fan? You may have to put dampers on the ductwork to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll have a single pole double throw switch controlling a ceiling fan in the up position and a switched outlet in the down position. This will work but keep in mind that when the ceiling fan is on and the outlet off, you're timer in the outlet will lose it's setting. You'll also need that outlet to be GFCI protected. You might consider a switch with the "center off" position.

Comment: I have the GFCI already.  I'll look for a "center off" switch.  I think that would be a good idea.